Why is only picture on left button update and not on up and right one when I press key on keyboard?
I have written little program i C with GTK3, so basically I have there button and I want to change pictures on them when I press left, up, or right key on keyboard, the issue is that what ever arrow I press the image is updated only on left arrow place holder. Here is my code
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *button_l;
GtkWidget *button_r;
GtkWidget *button_up;
gboolean left_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
gboolean right_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
gboolean up_arrow_pressed = FALSE;

void set_button_icon(GtkWidget *button, const gchar *icon_name) {
    GdkPixbuf *icon = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(icon_name, NULL);
    if (icon == NULL) {
        g_printerr("Error loading image: %s\n", icon_name);
        return;
    }
    GtkWidget *image_widget = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(icon);
    gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(button), image_widget);
}

gboolean on_key_press(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer user_data) {
    if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Left) {
        if (!left_arrow_pressed) {
            left_arrow_pressed = TRUE;
            g_print("Left arrow key pressed.\n");
        }
        set_button_icon(GTK_WIDGET(user_data), "pressed_icon_l.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Right) {
        if (!right_arrow_pressed) {
            right_arrow_pressed = TRUE;
            g_print("Right arrow key pressed.\n");
        }
        set_button_icon(GTK_WIDGET(user_data), "pressed_icon_r.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Up) {
        if (!up_arrow_pressed) {
            up_arrow_pressed = TRUE;
            g_print("Up arrow key pressed.\n");
        }
        set_button_icon(GTK_WIDGET(user_data), "pressed_icon_up.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    }
    return FALSE; // Event not handled
}

gboolean on_key_release(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer user_data) {
    if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Left) {
        left_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
        set_button_icon(GTK_WIDGET(user_data), "initial_icon_l.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Right) {
        right_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
        set_button_icon(GTK_WIDGET(user_data), "initial_icon_r.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Up) {
        up_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
        set_button_icon(GTK_WIDGET(user_data), "initial_icon_up.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    }
    return FALSE; // Event not handled
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "GladeUI_2.glade", NULL);
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
    button_l = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_l"));
    button_r = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_r"));
    button_up = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_up"));

    set_button_icon(button_l, "initial_icon_l.png");
    set_button_icon(button_r, "initial_icon_r.png");
    set_button_icon(button_up, "initial_icon_up.png");

    g_signal_connect(window, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), button_l);
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_release), button_l);
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), button_r);
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_release), button_r);
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), button_up);
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_release), button_up);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    g_object_unref(builder);

    return 0;
}

Here is my Glade file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_l">
            <property name="width-request">50</property>
            <property name="height-request">50</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
            <signal name="key-press-event" handler="on_button_l_pressed" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="pressed" handler="on_button_l_pressed" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">10</property>
            <property name="y">100</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_r">
            <property name="width-request">50</property>
            <property name="height-request">50</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
            <signal name="key-press-event" handler="on_button_r_pressed" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="pressed" handler="on_button_r_pressed" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">200</property>
            <property name="y">100</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_up">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">
</property>
            <property name="width-request">50</property>
            <property name="height-request">50</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
            <signal name="key-press-event" handler="on_button_up_pressed" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="pressed" handler="on_button_up_pressed" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">100</property>
            <property name="y">50</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>

So when I press left arrow I have this

But when I press UP arrow I have this

But i need it to be in the middle, any suggestion ?

You connect the same signal handler 3 times passing 3 different values as user data. I don't think this is allowed. You either get 3 callbacks, one for each data. That doesn't seem to happen. Or you only get one callback with first or last data provided. For you, it seems only the first call to g_signal_connect is executed and therefore the left button is updated. You should provide a struct holding pointers to all 3 buttons and pass it to your callback. Make sure the lifetime of that struct is static. Either use a global variable, a static local variable or use dynamic memory allocation.

@Gerhardh Yep you are totally right I',m calling signal handler 3 times, that the issue, fixed tnx
